# How to make post to AWS elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have uploaded my .csv files on the AWS s3.

Now I need to move it from AWS s3 to Aws eleastic search. Can someone please guide me about the right strategy to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

S3 (Trigger) --> Lambda (Add data to your ES domain)

**Lamda Responsibilities:**

Load each record from file and send it to elastic search domain.

**Sample Code:**

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need some thing in java. I have csv file in the s3, need to convert to blob data type and save in the aws Elastic search

Comment: Use the Elastic search documentation and take it from there, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticsearch/package-summary.html